# ggplot will automatically sort in alphabetical order instead of sorting based on dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am still new to R and Rstudio. I am using 2 of 20 columns to run a regression analysis for a master's thesis:

Cook_County_Data

| q25d | a_total |
| --- | --- |
| Strongly agree | 36% |
| Agree | 39% |
| Neither agree nor disagree | 11% |
| Disagree | 10% |
| Strongly Disagree | 4% |
| Don't Know | 0% |
| Skipped | 0% |
| Refused | 0% |

I ran this script to clean and create a scatterplot of the data (The original dataset was called q25d and it contained NA values):

```
library(tidyverse)
View(q25d)
q25d %>%
  na.omit()
Cook_County_Data <- q25d %>% 
  na.omit()
View(Cook_County_Data)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Cook_County_Data , aes(x = a_total ,
                              y = q25d )) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

While it did clean and create a scatterplot, for some reason the script put the q25d column in alphabetical order instead of being in the order it was originally in
[q25_and_a_total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9460P.png)

Comment: If you want a specific order then you have to convert your variable to a factor, e.g. to use the order of the data try with `y = factor(q25d, unique(q25d))` or `y = forcats::fct_inorder(q25d)`.